# "Unable to find partition size for path '/emmc'" when trying to install anything through TWRP on Levono TB2-X30L

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, lenovo

I have Lenovo TAB 2 A10-30 (TB2-X30L). While trying to install custom ROM or almost anything through TWRP, it shows:

```
E:Mount: Unable to find partition size for path '/emmc' 
E:Unmount: Unable to find partition for path '/emmc' 
E:Mount: Unable to find partition path for'/emmc'
```

Then after some process, it shows

```
E: Legacy property environment did not initialize successfully. Properties may not be detected
```

As of now, I don't have a ROM installed, so I am not able to use the device at all. When I try to install any ROM, it reboots and opens TWRP.

How can I fix these errors to be able to return to stock recovery or install any ROM?

Comment: How did your tablet got into this state? Didi you try to install a new ROM or did this occur without any special action? If I am not mistaken Lenovo TB2 X30L is a pretty old tablet, released with Android 5. Therefore one potential reason is a defect flash memory chip.

Comment: I was trying to install the stock rom so I think I have wiped everything as I thought I can install the stock room with TWRP

Comment: Was this working prior to trying to install the factory ROM? How did you "wipe everything" off the tablet? If you go into TWRP and Mount, can you mount any partition, or in Advanced, then File Manager, can you access any partition?

Comment: If you mean by this the, the tablet, yeah It was working fine. I did use wipe, format data, and advanced wipe as I remember. When I enter mount I am able to disable or enable MTP for System, data, cache and MicroSD partitions. Throug advanced then file manager I am able to access all files inside /. Like root, emc, sys Nd etc